# probabilities with small numbers

Tags: probability, product, arbitrary-precision

I am working with large amounts of probabilities that I multiply so i quickly obtain very small numbers. But it seems that python finally store the final result as zero.

to overpass this difficutly, I decided to sum the logs of these probabilities (instead of directly multiplying the probabilities). This strategy returns a negative number (call it c) as expected.

But then, if I want to apply the exponential on c (to come back on the real value of my product of probabilities), I obtain the value zero because c is too largely negative (something like -123445,4).

How could I overpass this problem?

Comment: You could try to use a data type which has more precision

Comment: @ helb: I tried to write a=long(exp(-35885))  but it always returns 0...  should I have done something else?

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to use numbers of that magnitude you should use a specialized library which can handle arbitrary floating point precision. Check out [mpmath](http://code.google.com/p/mpmath/) or [bigfloat package](http://pythonhosted.org/bigfloat/) for example.

Computers natively only support number down to approximately exp(-300). Alternatively, you could restrict your code to store only the exponent and never convert it in a decimal representation.